# XmlSerializer.Serialize exception: "The type [type] was not expected."

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize this class:

```
[XmlRoot("ArrayOfEvent")]
public class EventList
{
    public EventList()
    {

    }

    public EventList(IEnumerable<Event> items)
    {
        Items = items;
    }

    [XmlArray("")]
    public IEnumerable<Event> Items { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the `Event` class contained in `EventList.Items`:

```
public class Event
{
    [XmlElement]
    public string ID { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public string Location { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public DateTime? StartTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public DateTime? EndTime { get; set; }

    [XmlElement]
    public bool? AllDay { get; set; }
}
```

And here's where the error occurs:

```
public static XmlDocument ToXmlDocument<T>(T obj)
{
    var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
    var nav = xmlDocument.CreateNavigator();

    if (nav != null)
    {
        using (var writer = nav.AppendChild())
        {
            var ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
            ser.Serialize(writer, obj); //throws exception
        }
    }

    return xmlDocument;
}
```

The `XmlSerializer` gives me this error when calling `Serialize()`:

```
The type Domain.EventList was not expected. 
Use the XmlInclude or SoapInclude attribute to specify types that are not 
known statically.
```

I've tried using `[XmlInclude(typeof(EventList))]` on the `EventList` class as well as the `Event` class but neither of those ideas worked. I'm not sure what else to do.

Is anybody familiar with this issue? How can I resolve it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps a stupid comment, but you've used [Serializable] attribute?

Comment: @gleng `XmlSerializer` isn't in the least bit  interested in `[Serializable]`

Comment: @gleng Yes I did try that, but no effect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, lists are kinda special to `XmlSerializer`. You will have a lot more success if you declare the DTO to have a concrete list type, for example:

```
[XmlArray("")]
public List<Event> Items { get; set; }
```

Comment: Unfortunately this didn't change anything, either. Same error.

Comment: @kehrk firstly, it only recognises (as lists) things that implement `IList<T>` (or it might be `IList` plus a non-object indexer - that is a common framework pattern) - but secondly, it only works with concrete list types: if you try it with an interface, it throws an exception saying that it isn't happy with that. Presumably due to reconstruction. There are serializers that don't impose these demands, but this is simply how `XmlSerializer` works

Comment: @kehrk I tried this example - it worked fine for my scenario where that was the list. Can you give a full (runnable) example of it failing?

Comment: I added all the relevant code to the OP. Hope it helps. Thanks for looking into it.

Comment: @kehrk with the edit: can you show the code that calls `ToXmlDocument<T>(T obj)` ? I wonder if the thing you are passing as the parameter is not typed as `EventList`, but is something else - `object`, `ISomeInterface`, `SomeBaseType`, etc

Comment: I actually solved this issue by solving another issue. Your suggestion of using `List` worked, thanks for the help.